# evitar demasiadas consultas en búsqueda automática jquery onchange añadir retraso

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo una barra de búsqueda la cual funcionaba en sus inicios haciendo click en el botón de búsqueda o presionando la tecla enter, ahora necesito que sea automática pero también deseo que no haga la consulta inmediatamente al presionar cualquier tecla porque eso genera múltiples consultas.

Cómo puedo añadir un retraso para evitar que busque varias veces mientras el usuario escribe lo que quiere buscar?

he añadido un timeout de 5 segundos pero lo único que hace es esperar 5 segundos y luego ejecuta la acción la cantidad de veces que el input ha cambiado (si escribo 3 letras, tarda 5 segundos y hace 3 búsquedas)

este es mi código con el timeout que no funciona tal y como quiero

```
            $('#search_site_input').on('input', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    searchSite();
                }, 5000);
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar un solo temporizador, asignado a una variable para poder cancelarlo y, al final, la petición se ejecutará solo una vez. El tiempo debe ser corto, de acuerdo a lo que un usuario tarda al teclear lo que desea buscar, puede ser entre 200 y 350 milisegundos para que pueda ser efectivo y el usuario no note la espera.

```
// Crear una variable para controlar el temporizador
let searchTimer;

// En las funciones de botón, tecla Enter y cambios en campo
// solo ejecuta la función
$('#search_site_input').on('input', searchSite);

function searchSite() {
    // Cancelar temporizador
    clearTimeout(searchTimer);
    // Analiza si hay valor para buscar
    let search = $('#search_site_input').val().trim();
    // De preferencia, busca solo si se teclearon dos o más caracteres
    if(search.length < 2) {
        return;
    }
    // Coloca la petición en el temporizador
    searchTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax(/* Aquí el código de la petición */);
    }, 200); // Ajusta el tiempo a tu gusto y necesidades
}
```

De esta forma, también evitas que se hagan varias búsquedas en clics consecutivos.