# acelerar la velocidad de busqueda de registros Laravel

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, ajax

Bien, no se si esto sea un problema en si, pero me gustaria un poco de ayuda.

Estoy haciendo un `search` con peticiones `Http_Request`, estoy usando el framework de Laravel para esto y mysql como motor de base de datos.

Hasta ahora va bien, hace las busquedas y no me arroja problemas pero me gustaria saber si se puede acelerar el proceso de busqueda.

```
    searchInput.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
    let user = document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
    if(user != ""){
        
        const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = "/Paciente/search/"+user;
        http.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (this.readyState==4 && this.status == 200) {
                let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById('table-body').innerHTML = "";
                response.forEach(paciente => {
                    let addPaciente = `<tr id="tr-table">
                        <th scope="row">`+paciente.ID+`</th>
                            <td>`+paciente.nombre+`</td>
                            <td>`+paciente.apellidos+`</td>
                            <td>`+paciente.carnet+`</td>
                            <td>`+paciente.fecha_nacimiento+`</td>
                            <td>`+paciente.telefono+`</td>
                            <td>`+paciente.direccion+`</td>
                            <td id="`+paciente.Barrio_ID+`">`+paciente.barrio_nombre+`</td>
                            <td>`+paciente.strikes+`</td>
                            <td><div class="size-show"><a href="#" id="showUser" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".showUserModal" class="showUser" ><i class="far fa-eye"></i> Ver</a></div> </td>
                            <td><div class="size-delete"><a href="#" id="deleteUser" class="deleteUser"><i class="far fa-trash"></i> Eliminar</a></td>
                        </tr>`;
                    
                    document.getElementById('table-body').innerHTML += addPaciente;

                });
            }
        }
        http.open('GET', url);
        http.send();
    }
    
})
```

Estoy haciendolo asi... esta es la peticion.

Y desde el controlador de Laravel, estoy haciendolo asi

```
 public function search($user){
    $pacientes = DB::table('pacientes')
    ->where('pacientes.carnet','like','%'.$user.'%')
    ->orWhere('pacientes.apellidos','like','%'.$user.'%')
    ->get();
    return $pacientes;
}
```

La consulta es sencilla, mi problema es que ahora mismo tengo como 30 registros de prueba, y siento que se demora, no mucho, poco mas de 1 segundo, pero me da miedo, ya que la base de datos tendra unos `60 mil` registros, y no quisiera que demore no se, 15 o 20 segundos haciendo una sola busqueda.

Entonces, mi pregunta es... ¿El código, se ve bien o hay alguna forma de mejorar para que las busquedas las haga mas rapido? (No estoy usando eloquent, pero no me molestaria si eso aumenta la velocidad de busqueda)

Comment: Primero te recomiendo, hacer uso de paginación ya que si dices que vas a tener 60mil registros, no puedes hacer simplemente un get() de todos los datos, se demorará bastante, ocupa render y desde el controlador te encargas de renderizar los datos

Comment: acá te dejo un ejemplo de como funciona https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-8-view-render-example

Comment: Si, para cargar la tabla, estoy vista que contiene la tabla, estoy usando `pagination` pero para el buscador no. Aunque seria una muy buena opcion.

Comment: Indexar las columnas de tu base de datos acelera considerablemente la búsqueda. Por otro lado, hay que evitar usar el wildcard `%` al inicio, ya que con eso haces un escaneo de toda la tabla. Las búsquedas con `LIKE` afectan el performance, así que debes tener cuidado con ello. Mejor buscar a full-text.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias enserio son de mucha ayuda. Ya investigue sobre lo de indexar los campos y lo aplique a los campos escenciales. Y tambien modifiqué lo del  LIKE, para que solo acepte un valor especifico y no busque tantos.

Comment: Aparte de los buenos consejos que ya te dieron, te recomiendo comenzar a buscar a partir de que se hayan tecleado 2 o más caracteres y usar un [temporizador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/468125/54039) para evitar acumular peticiones cuando el usuario teclea muy rápido.

Comment: @Triby , gracias por el consejo. Aunque opte mejor por asignar un botón que ejecuta la funcion de buscar. Es mas practico que hacer una peticion por cada letra. Ademas de que usaré solo los apellidos o numeros de carnet. Y esos datos no es algo que el cliente pueda olvidar. Pero muchas gracias, en algun punto implementare lo del `keyup` y no habia considerado lo que me dijiste. Procurare recordarlo