# Cómo evitar demaciadas llamadas al servidor por KeyPress, KeyUp

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Tengo un input que me sirve como una barra de búsqueda:

`<input id="inputbnombre" name="inputbnombre" type="text" onKeyUp="barra_busqueda(this)">`

Y la función `barra_busqueda(elem)` es esta:

```
$("#divload").load("buscar.php", {"nombre": $(elem).val(), "tipo": "agregar"}, function(response) {
            if(response!="nada"){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                if(obj.length>1){
                    $("#selectprod").attr("size",obj.length);
                }else{
                    $("#selectprod").attr("size","2");
                }
                $("#selectprod").html('');
                for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
                    $("#selectprod").append('<option class="text-center" value="'+obj[i].cod+'">'+obj[i].nombre+'</option>');
                }
            }else{
                $("#selectprod").attr("size","2");
                $("#selectprod").html('<option class="text-center" value="-1">NO HAY COINCIDENCIAS</option>');
            }
});
$("#selectprod").css({"display": "inline"});
```

El resultado lo muestro en un select para poder captar el evento Onchange, y el archivo buscar.php lo que hace es buscar una coincidencia en la base de datos con: `Select * from productos where nombre like '%$_REQUEST[nombre]%'`. La pregunta es, ya que es un evento OnkeyUp, y la velocidad a la que se escribe una letra aveces hace que el servidor o la función me mande error, cómo puedo hacer que se espere un segundo, osea que recién se ejecute la función cuando lleva 1 segundo sin escribir nada en el input, no creo que sleep() de php o SetTimeOut de Javascript me puedan ayudar en este caso.

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/468125/54039), donde se incluye un temporizador para evitar que se acumulen peticiones. Además, es mejor si usas el evento `input` para que funcione tanto al teclear como cortar y pegar texto.

Comment: Podrías guardar temporalmente los resultados de las búsquedas para que tarde menos la próxima vez. También podrías limitar las peticiones un tiempo.

Comment: ¿Y cual es el error que el servidor o la función te manda?  ¿Que dice?

Comment: También puedes utilizar una técnica llamada [debounce](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo así, dejo ejemplo funcional:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <label for="input">Try it:
        <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Type something here..."/>
    </label>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript (archivo a parte en misma carpeta que el html, se llama app.js)**

```
let timer = 0;
const delayValue = 500 //Aquí seteamos el tiempo de espera en milisegundos
$("#input").keyup(function () {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    //Hacemos algo
    console.log("Se terminó el tiempo, texto ingresado: " + $("#input").val());
  }, delayValue);
});
```

Lo que hace es cada vez que se detecta un keyup borra el timer que está corriendo de 0 a 500, entonces si si esperan esos 500ms se ejecuta el código (en este caso un console.log), si no se llega a cumplir antes de que exista otro keyup, se borra el timer devuelta al haber otro keyup y arranca la cuenta de 0 y así consecutivamente, hasta que se deje de presionar teclas por 500ms o el tiempo seteado en delayValue ya que lo toma de ahí.

Espero te sirva, quedo a las ordenes.

---

Dejo JavaScript con JS Vanilla y jQuery más prolijos, con un destructuring de dos niveles y backticks en el clg.

```
//V1 con jQuery
let timer = 0;
const delayValue = 700; //Aquí seteamos el tiempo de espera en milisegundos
$("#searchedValue").keyup(function ({ target: { value } }) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    //Hacemos algo
    console.log(`Se terminó el tiempo, texto ingresado: ${value}`);
  }, delayValue);
});
```

---

```
// V2 con JS Vanilla
let timer = 0;
const delayValue = 700; //Aquí seteamos el tiempo de espera en milisegundos
const searchedValue = document.getElementById("searchedValue");

searchedValue.addEventListener("keyup", ({ target: { value } }) => {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    //Hacemos algo
    console.log(`Se terminó el tiempo, texto ingresado: ${value}`);
  }, delayValue);
});
```